# how to activate json extension in php7?

Tags: php, json

I am running PHP 7.0.29 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and when I try to access phpmyadmin I get this error message `"The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."` I have enable `json.so` by including `extension=json.so` in `php.ini`, although the only `json.so` files I have in my machine are under `/usr/lib/php5 and /user/lib/php`. Any help on how to activate Json extension in PHP7?

Comment: Have you checked `sudo apt-cache search php7.0-*` to see if it available? If so `apt-get update` `apt-get install php7.0-json` should work.

Comment: Hi @Hexchaimen although `$ sudo php -v` showed me php 7.0 as the running version, the active module was php5. I disabled php5 and enabled php7 and started working. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get install php7.0-json`